# How to find the mouse position inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse-position

I used this code, but it's well only for Y-coordinate

```
$('div').mousemove(function(e){
    var x = Math.floor(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
    var y = Math.floor(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);

    $('.status').html(x+' '+y);

});
```

X-coordinate show me wrong values.

Comment: what means wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Does anything change if you replace

```
var x = Math.floor(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
var y = Math.floor(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);
```

with

```
var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
```

Comment: yes, this is the same, but my code was a lit bit wrong, lol [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/mkZP2/)